# Is angular ui-router multiple views order important?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have multiple views in angular ui-router state. code below:

```
 .state('user.dash', {
     url: "/dash",
  views: {
    'contentView':{
      templateUrl: "...",
      controller: "..."
    },
    'headerView':{
      templateUrl: "...",
      controller: "..."
    },
   'leftSideMenuView':{
     templateUrl: "...",
     controller: "..."
   }
  }
```

And as my "contentView" takes too much time to load, because it is calling several http requests, I want to know if (in angular concept) the definition order of these multiple views is important?

I mean, if the definition of `leftSideMenuView` before `contentView` could help me to load first my `leftSideMenuView` without waiting for `contentView` ?

Comment: you should use resolves in your views...

Comment: So akram, what Mikey said is correct - are you seeing one view pop up before the other is ready? By using resolves to pre-load what you need, the views won't come up until the data is ready. Is that sort of what you are going for? As far as the actual answer - I don't know if they actually load in order, resolves don't since they are async.

Comment: Thanks, Mikey , VSO !
what I need is to prevent a view from starting to load until the other view finishes loading. I don't care if called data is  ready or not.
So, I think that I should use resolves between views in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. Please see the following plunkr for reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/6xRCYOGsjBk1Wlrdeliz?p=preview .

As you can see, the plunkr shows examples of both mimicking a long operation on both as in a resolve as suggested by others as well as from the controller. What we can see is that if we use resolves, the view will still take the same amount to load, but the subviews will not be rendered until EVERYTHING has been resolved. If we instead make the calls from the controllers, we can see that order does not matter since each the view has already loaded and the calls are handled by each of the controllers after that.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@0.2.15" data-semver="0.2.15" src="//rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.15/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h4>First View</h4>
    <div ui-view="first"></div>

    <h4>Second View</h4>
    <div ui-view="second"></div>

    <h4>Third View</h4>
    <div ui-view="third"></div>

    <h4>Fourth View</h4>
    <div ui-view="fourth"></div>

    <h4>Fifth View</h4>
    <div ui-view="fifth"></div>
  </body>

</html>

// Code goes here

angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        url:'/',
        // templateUrl: 'layout.html',
        views: {
          'first': {
            template: '<div>{{text}}</div>',
            controller: 'theWaitCtrl',
            resolve: {
              'msg': function($q, $timeout, RandomNumberService) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                var waitDuration = RandomNumberService.getRandomNumber();

                $timeout(function() {
                  deferred.resolve('View resolved after ' + waitDuration + ' milliseconds');
                }, waitDuration);

                return deferred.promise;
              }
            }
          },
          'second': {
            template: '<div>{{text}}</div>',
            controller: 'theCtrl'
          },
          'third': {
            template: '<div>{{text}}</div>',
            controller: 'theCtrl'
          },
          'fourth': {
            template: '<div>{{text}}</div>',
            controller: 'theCtrl'
          },
          'fifth': {
            template: '<div>{{text}}</div>',
            controller: 'theWaitCtrl',
            resolve: {
              'msg': function($q, $timeout, RandomNumberService) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                var waitDuration = RandomNumberService.getRandomNumber();

                $timeout(function() {
                  deferred.resolve('View resolved after ' + waitDuration + ' milliseconds');
                }, waitDuration);

                return deferred.promise;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  })
  .controller('theCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, RandomNumberService) {
    $scope.text = 'loading...';
    var randomNumberOfMs = RandomNumberService.getRandomNumber();

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.text = 'loaded after ' + randomNumberOfMs + 'milliseconds';
    }, randomNumberOfMs);
  })
  .controller('theWaitCtrl', function($scope, msg) {
    $scope.text = msg;
  })
  .factory('RandomNumberService', function() {
    function getRandomNumber() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
    }

    return {
      getRandomNumber: getRandomNumber
    };
  })
  ;
```